# mysql too many connections

Tags: .net, mysql

Too many connections - End of inner exception stack trace - I get this exception for an application running mysql as backend and .net.

Any thoughts on the source of this, our DB guy tells that max connections has not reached, so this error is not because of max connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While the database may not have reached the max connections it is possible for the user to reach a threshold of connections.  I find that this will occur when the .NET connector does not (or you haven't) closed the connection cleanly.

Comment: Here's the only thing that worked in our case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226015/error-too-many-connections-on-codeigniter-website